# What is this texture/filter?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, minimalistic

I'm working on a personal project and I'm looking for inspiration. I've found something interesting but I doesn't know what it is nor how to do it… Could you help me answering these question ?

[image: Black Minimal Abstract Design]

Comment: I'd look up tutorials on how to add "dust" or "film grain"

Comment: I didn't think of dust... I'm looking into it !